# How do I make spaces between numbers in a random number generated app in C++?

Tags: c++

I need to be able to have spaces come up between each number. Here is my code. Any help would be awesome! This app allows you too have 6 rows of 6 numbers generated for your insta pick numbers between 1 - 49, it has to pick two rows of 6 numbers, 1 - 49 for twist  and 1 row of 6 numbers for tag.

```
    #include <iostream> 
    #include <iomanip>
    #include <cstdlib>
    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
    {
cout << "*** LOTTO  MAX  INSTA  PICK ***" << endl;
cout<< " " << endl << endl;
    }

    {
cout << "Your Insta Pick Numbers" << endl;
cout<< " " << endl << endl;
    }
for (int counter = 1; counter <= 24; ++ counter)
{

    cout << setw(1) << (1 + rand() % 49);


    if (counter % 6 == 0)
        cout << endl;
}
{
    cout<< " " << endl << endl;
    cout<< " " << endl << endl;
}
{
cout << "Your Twist Numbers" << endl;
cout<< " " << endl << endl;
    }
for (int counter = 1; counter <= 12; ++ counter)
{

    cout << setw(1) << (1 + rand() % 49) , "  ";


    if (counter % 6 == 0)
        cout << endl;

}
{
    cout<< " " << endl << endl;
    cout<< " " << endl << endl;
}


{
cout << "Your Tag Numbers" << endl;
cout<< " " << endl << endl;
    }
for (int counter = 1; counter <= 6; ++ counter)
{

    cout << setw(1) << (1 + rand() % 12);


    if (counter % 6 == 0)
        cout << endl;

}
{
    cout<< " " << endl << endl;
   cout<< " " << endl << endl;
}
{
cout << "Thank you for playing!! please check ticket a year minus a day               from date of purchase" <<endl;
}
    };
```

Comment: why don't you either use of width of 3 or write a space? BTW, is it intentional that your numbers could include duplicates? Personally, I would fill an array with the desired range of numbers, `std::random_shuffle()` the array, and use the numbers from this array. BTW, **don't** use `std::endl`! Just write a newline `\n` unless you really want the output buffer to be flushed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost had it when you did

```
cout << setw(1) << (1 + rand() % 49) , "  ";
```

but that doesn't do what you think it does. It evaluates two expressions, separated by a comma - `cout << setw(1) << (1 + rand() % 49)` and `"  "`. The first does the `setw` and prints `(1 + rand() % 49)`, and the second one just evaluates to itself and has no effect. Remember that `<<` is the output operator for `cout`, so you just need to change the comma to a `<<`:

```
cout << setw(1) << (1 + rand() % 49) << "  ";
```

The same thing goes for the other places you are printing numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Use `cout << setw(1) << (1 + rand() % 49) << "  ";` in your loop. (Note that `,` was replaced with `<<`.